# PSGI application with Apache2 using Plack::Handler::Apache2 results in 'not found'

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apache2, plack, psgi

first time poster, long time lurker here.

Im using a tiny PSGI application in plackup, but id like to switch to Apache2 for subdomains. I run the application with '*plackup /home/ath88/work/kolle/script/dir.psgi -port 80*'. It runs perfectly on plackup. The application is quite simple and can be found at https://github.com/ath88/Kolletilmelding/blob/master/script/dir.psgi

But, i would like to run Apache2 instead of plackup for obvious reasons. For this i want to use Plack::Handler::Apache2. My VirtualHost looks as follows:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName aths.dk
      ServerAdmin asbjoern@gmail.com
      <Location />
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
        PerlSetVar psgi_app /home/ath88/work/kolle/script/dir.psgi
      </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Apache2 restarts fine. But when i attempt to visit aths.dk i mere get a 404 not found. The directory for the application is correct, since it results in a 500 Internal Error. Looking in the apache2/error.log i get this: **[Irrelevant, see edit]**

```
    [Wed Oct 05 21:32:16 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed Oct 05 21:32:17 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu) mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

This happens every time i restart Apache2.

I have spent 4 hours trying to debug this. I am totally mindboggled.

**Edit:** Turns out the SIGTERM was from stopping Apache2 for restarting. It doesn't happen when i start it. Silly me.

Comment: Perhaps add some output from the access.log as well to see what it is requesting?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your setup will benefit from a reverse HTTP proxy setup.

You can start your Plack application manually, and you can bind it to `127.0.0.1:9001` instead of `127.0.0.1:80`, in which case you need a privileged user ( TCP port below 1024 ).

Then a reverse HTTP proxy config that should work could be like this one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName aths.dk
        ServerAdmin asbjoern@gmail.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/aths.dk-error.log
        TransferLog /var/log/apache2/aths.dk.log
        DocumentRoot /var/www/aths.dk
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9001/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This should work. The weakest link will, however, still be plackup as it is only intended for development.